# Repository pattern and service layer implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, repository-pattern

I'm using the generic repository and unit of work pattern for my mvc4 website.

Now I have the situation, that I want to delete a user of my system.
In the delete code I must delete some more entries in other tables (comments, accessrights, ..).

The simplest solution is to create a `UserRepository` which inherits from `GenericRepository<User>` and modify the delete method to delete the data in other tables. But that means my `UserRepository` would access to other tables, which should have their own repository classes, right?

I've read about a service layer, which is between my business logic and my repositories.

What is the best practise here and how looks a implementation of the service layer?

And is there still any requirement for have custom implemented repositores like `UserRepository` if I use a service layer or should I only have generic repositories and do my logic in the service class?

Example code:

```
class UserRepository
{
    public void Delete(User entity)
    {
        var userComments = Context.UserComments.Get(comment => comment.UserId == entity.Id);

        foreach (var comment in userComments)
        {
            Context.UserComments.Remove(comment);
        }

        //
        // same for access rights here
        //

        Context.Users.Remove(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: one way to avoid having to do that manually would be to take advantage of CASCADE DELETE... (look at .WillCascadeOnDelete() in your mapping)

Comment: The delete code is just one example, I have much more queries which will access multiple tables, e.g. for returning report data for users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The repository pattern was popularized with the DDD (Domain Driven Design) movement. In DDD, it is recommended that you DON'T create a repository per table, but one per aggregate root.. So, while you might have a table for a user, user orders, and user comments, you could decide that the User is an aggregate root and then you would only create a user repository and add your methods there.

Anyway, regardless of whether you care about DDD, I'd add the logic to your user repo, it makes sense to be there rather than any other repo.

You *could* create a service layer and create a service class for this, but service classes are really not useful for this - you're not really benefiting anything in this scenario.

Comment: This is very interesting, I understood it to have exactly one repository per table.

Comment: generic repos are fine, but dont be afraid of adding logic to them.. You need to delete a user so that should be a method on your user reop, which should also delete the user comments etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
.WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

on `modelBuilder`

To answer your questions about services. You ideally want your service to perform additional logic on the entities/objects that your repository has retrieved for you. In this case, you don't really want a service to be deleting rows as this is the responsibility of your repository.

Services are good. In MVC, you call service methods from your controllers. Ideally, interfaces so you can test them easily.

Comment: According to the answer of Matt Roberts: Which responsibility has the repository and which the service? I don't understand the difference here.

Comment: The way I see it, a service wraps everything up in a nice usable object for use from your controllers. Put common tasks in the service as public methods, without a service these common tasks would be mixed in with calls to repository methods in your controller or in a helper class or something. Ideally, you have a light weight controller which just does what it's supposed to; return stuff to views and take in stuff from the view. The service does all the heavy lifting. The repository uses the ORM or SQL or whatever to get or know how to get (perform CRUD) data from your data source.

Comment: Yup - simple data ops are the job of the repoisitory - so you dont get anything from having a service here. But say you needed to merge users from 2 sources to create a master list - this would be a good case for a service class - that could internally call 2 different reopisitories to get the data

Comment: Good example. I'd say pragmatically, once your controllers start to get big, refactor into a service class.

Comment: Actually I'm using AutoMapper to create ViewModels to return stuff to my views. If i understand you correctly, a service class could replace the need of AutoMapper, because I have the possibility to create the ViewModel in the service?

Comment: Hmm, not really no. An AutoMapper only helps you map similar objects automatically.

Comment: AutoMapper and Service have different roles. Your service co-ordinates operations between one or more classes (repositories in this case).

Answer (score 0):

As you said, service layer is help you to separate between business logic and repositories. The main idea here is dependency injection

```
public interface IUserService
{
    public void Delete(User entity);
}

//
// This class would be used Linq to Entities 
public class LinqUserService : IUserService 
{
    public void Delete (User entity)
    {
    }  
}

// 
// This class would be used Sql command
public class SqlUserService : IUserService
{
    public void Delete (User entity)
    {
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm using Ninject to inject my `UnitOfWork` class to my Controllers. Which injection do you mean exactly should done for which classes?